I can't seem to find out why my code is failing to get a snapshot in my react expo project
import { View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { captureRef } from 'react-native-view-shot';
import { type ImageSource } from "expo-image";

import Button from '@/components/Button';
import ImageViewer from '@/components/ImageViewer';
import IconButton from '@/components/IconButton';
import CircleButton from '@/components/CircleButton';
import EmojiPicker from '@/components/EmojiPicker';
import EmojiList from '@/components/EmojiList';
import EmojiSticker from '@/components/EmojiSticker';

const PlaceholderImage = require('@/assets/images/background-image.png');

export default function Index() {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [showAppOptions, setShowAppOptions] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [pickedEmoji, setPickedEmoji] = useState<ImageSource | undefined>(undefined);
  const [status, requestPermission] = MediaLibrary.usePermissions();
  const imageRef = useRef<View>(null);

  if (status === null) {
    requestPermission();
  }

  const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ['images'],
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setSelectedImage(result.assets[0].uri);
      setShowAppOptions(true);
    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    setShowAppOptions(false);
  };

  const onAddSticker = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const onModalClose = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };
`problematic function`
  const onSaveImageAsync = async () => {
    try {
      if (!imageRef.current) {
        throw new Error('View reference is not available');
      }

      const localUri = await captureRef(imageRef.current, {
        height: 440,
        quality: 1,
        format: 'png', // Explicitly set format
        result: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'tmpfile' : 'data-uri', // Different result types for iOS/Android
      });

      if (!localUri) {
        throw new Error('Failed to capture view');
      }

      await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(localUri);
      alert('Saved!');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <View ref={imageRef} collapsable={false}>
          <ImageViewer imgSource={PlaceholderImage} selectedImage={selectedImage} />
          {pickedEmoji && <EmojiSticker imageSize={40} stickerSource={pickedEmoji} />}
        </View>
      </View>
      {showAppOptions ? (
        <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
          <View style={styles.optionsRow}>
            <IconButton icon="refresh" label="Reset" onPress={onReset} />
            <CircleButton onPress={onAddSticker} />
            <IconButton icon="save-alt" label="Save" onPress={onSaveImageAsync} />
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Button theme="primary" label="Choose a photo" onPress={pickImageAsync} />
          <Button label="Use this photo" onPress={() => setShowAppOptions(true)} />
        </View>
      )}
      <EmojiPicker isVisible={isModalVisible} onClose={onModalClose}>
        <EmojiList onSelect={setPickedEmoji} onCloseModal={onModalClose} />
      </EmojiPicker>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#25292e',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  footerContainer: {
    flex: 1 / 3,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  optionsContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 80,
  },
  optionsRow: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});

this is the page im getting the problem, the error is probably something with the onSaveImageAsync function.
I could not get ChatGPT to find the problem
the message I get when I try to save is

[Error: Failed to snapshot view tag 14]

I tried asking ChatGPT and Claudia but they could not help,
this code is also the original tutorial code from
https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/screenshot/

There are several alternative solutions which you can try. They might or might not work.


Adding collapsable={false} to the View component which you want to capture. This might temporarily fix this issue.


Test with Android and iOS. This issue might happen in Android but not in iOS.


Change from View to ViewShot tag.



"I tried asking ChatGPT and Claudia but they could not help," does not feel like it adds any useful information to your question.  In fact, I'm hoping it's true of every question asked on Stack Overflow that the asker has spent a reasonable amount of effort on answering their own question using the various of resources available to us the internet.  If it had helped, you wouldn't be asking.

If you're using Expo SDK 52, the issue is likely related to that. I recently updated from SDK 51 to 52 and experienced the same error. This update also involved upgrading the react-native-view-shot library from version 3.8.0 to 4.0.0.

it works changing snapshotContentContainer: true to snapshotContentContainer: false
with expo 52
